# Impresso de membro de struct imprime algo estranho

Tags: c, c++, struct

Estou fazendo um trabalho que usa `struct` esta tudo certo mas na hora de listar a última sai com um caractere estranho.

[image: mostrando erro]

O meu código está assim

```
struct livro_cadastro{
    int codigo;
    char obra[30]; 
    char autor[30]; 
    char editora[30];
};

int main(){
    int p, codigo2, i;
    struct livro_cadastro livro[5];
    p = 1;
    codigo2 = 1;

        while ( p != 0 ){
            printf("\nMENU. \n\n"
            "1 - Inserir um novo cadastro.\n"
            "2 - Mostrar todos os cadastros.\n"
            "0 - Encerrar.\n");
        printf("\nEscolha sua opcao:");
        scanf("%d", &p );
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (p){

    case 1:
        if (codigo2 <= 5){

            printf("\nNovo cadastro.\n");
            printf("Codigo:%d \n", codigo2);
            printf("Insira o nome do livro: \n");
            fgets(livro[codigo2].obra, 30, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Insira o nome do autor: \n");
            fgets(livro[codigo2].autor, 30, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Insira o nome da editora: \n");
            fgets(livro[codigo2].editora, 30, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);
            codigo2++;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nSistema de cadastro lotado.\n");
        }
    break;

    case 2:
        if(codigo2 == 1){
            printf("\nA lista esta vazia!\n");

        }
        else{
            printf("\nCadastros.\n");
            for(i = 1 ; i < codigo2 ; i++)
            {
                printf("\nCodigo:%d ", i);
                printf("\n\nNome do livro: %s\n",livro[i].obra);
                printf("Nome do autor: %s\n",livro[i].autor);
                printf("Nome da editora: %s\n",livro[i].editora);
            }

        }
    break;

    case 0:
        printf("Encerrando o programa.\n");


    default:
        printf("Opcao invalida!");
    break;
//  case 2:
//      desempilhando();
//  break;
//
//  case 3:
//      esvaziar_pilha();
//  break;
    }
}
return (0);

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O problema todo acontece porque o código tem algo conceitual errado, por isso eu arrumei o código todo, com código organizado sempre é mais fácil trabalhar. Iniciava com o código valendo 1, sendo que ele deveria ser um contador de quantos itens existem cadastrados, portanto deveria começar com 0. Quando começa com 1 você já começa cadastrar no segundo *slot* do *array*, dando o erro apresentado. Assim está certo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    char obra[30]; 
    char autor[30]; 
    char editora[30];
} Livro;

int main() {
    int codigo = 0;
    Livro livro[5];
    int op = 1;
    while (op != 0) {
        printf("\nMENU.\n"
        "1 - Inserir um novo cadastro.\n"
        "2 - Mostrar todos os cadastros.\n"
        "0 - Encerrar.\n");
        printf("\nEscolha sua opcao:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        int c; //para limpar buffer
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            if (codigo < 5) {
                printf("\nNovo cadastro.\n");
                printf("Codigo:%d \n", codigo);
                printf("Insira o nome do livro: \n");
                fgets(livro[codigo].obra, 30, stdin);
                printf("Insira o nome do autor: \n");
                fgets(livro[codigo].autor, 30, stdin);
                printf("Insira o nome da editora: \n");
                fgets(livro[codigo].editora, 30, stdin);
                codigo++;
            } else printf("\nSistema de cadastro lotado.\n");
        break;
        case 2:
            if (codigo == 0) printf("\nA lista esta vazia!\n");
            else {
                printf("\nCadastros.\n");
                for (int i = 0 ; i < codigo; i++) {
                    printf("\nCodigo:%d ", i);
                    printf("\nNome do livro: %s", livro[i].obra);
                    printf("Nome do autor: %s", livro[i].autor);
                    printf("Nome da editora: %s", livro[i].editora);
                }
            }
        break;
        case 0:
            printf("Encerrando o programa.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opcao invalida!");
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6Bgsc4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RightOffset). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/RightOffset.c).